# HQL hibernate errors out on AT TIME ZONE

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a query

```
Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT t " +
                        "FROM Tag AS t " +
                            "JOIN t.site s " +
                            "JOIN s.timezone tz " +     
                        "WHERE t.statusTypeId = 2 AND " +
                            "( t.startDate <= TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TO_CHAR(:startDate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24') AT TIME ZONE tz.name) OR t.startDate IS NULL) AND " +
                            "( t.endDate >= TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TO_CHAR(:endDate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24') AT TIME ZONE tz.name) OR t.endDate IS NULL )");
```

Hibernate throw an ERROR ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:212: unexpected token: AT

How can I use AT TINE ZONE in createQuery?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql query, then you need to use `createSQLQuery(String sqlquery)`

Please refer to [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html). createQuery(string queryString) accepts HQL query but not SQL query. Your query is SQL